# Showing a warning message to a user after login

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a Liferay application in which users have a "membership plan". When a user logs in, I need to check if their membership plan has expired and show them a warning message. (The membership plan is independent of the login functionality. The user can still login even though his/her membership plan has expired).

I thought of creating a post-login action. But I cannot access my service builder methods (`MemberPlanLocalServiceUtil.isPlanExpired()`) from this, or any other hooks that I create.

What approach should I use to solve this problem? Would an ext plugin be necessary here? Or can I do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around the problem. (It was one of those situations where a solution was needed quickly, and a dirty solution it is)

Here's what I did

I added a `LoginAction` in which I set a session attribute:

```
public void run(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ActionException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("LIFERAY_SHARED_checkMemberExpiry", true);
}
```

Then, in a portlet on the home page, I check if this session attribute is set, and show my warning message if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using the applicationContext.xml,create one applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF, place all the bean references in it.
Set the context parameter in Web.xml and also the listener class.

context parameter

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>portalContextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

listener class

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.spring.context.PortletContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SerializableSessionAttributeListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.HookContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

For reference you can check this post
http://www.liferay.com/zh/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/custom-velocity-tools-and-liferay-6-0

Answer (score 0):

You cat add the "post-login action" to the MemberPlan-Portlet (Plugin). For that you need to add hook to your portlet. The portlet schould extends the `login.events.post=com.mypackage.MyLoginPostAction`, see for details 
http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/extending-and-overriding-%3Cem%3Eportal-properties-lt-e-1 .